# Pivot values of two column into columns names

Tags: sql-server

I have a table as below

```
RowNamesCol1   RowNamesCol2   Col1   Col2  
Col1Row1       Col2Row1       1      4  
Col1Row2       Col2Row2       2      5  
Col1Row3       Col2Row3       3      6
```

I have came up with  the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT RowNamesCol1, RowNamesCol2, colnames, colvalues FROM PivUnPiv1
UNPIVOT
(colvalues FOR colnames IN (col1, col2)) AS unpivtable) as a
PIVOT
(MAX(Colvalues) FOR RowNamesCol2 IN ([Col2Row1], [Col2Row2], [Col2Row3])) AS P
) AS b
PIVOT
(MAX(Colnames) FOR RowNamesCol1 IN ([Col1Row1], [Col1Row2], [Col1Row3])) AS P2
```

The result is as follows:

```
Col2Row1 | Col2Row2   |Col2Row3   |Col1Row1   |Col1Row2   |Col1Row3
-------------------------------------------------------------------
NULL     | NULL       |3          |NULL       |NULL       |Col1
NULL     | NULL       |6          |NULL       |NULL       |Col2
NULL     | 2          |NULL       |NULL       |Col1       |NULL
NULL     | 5          |NULL       |NULL       |Col2       |NULL
1        | NULL       |NULL       |Col1       |NULL       |NULL
4        | NULL       |NULL       |Col2       |NULL       |NULL
```

But what I'm looking for is as follows:

```
________________________________________
| RNC1 |  Col1Row1 | Col1Row2 | Col1Row3|  
|---------------------------------------|  
| RNC2 |  Col2Row1 | Col2Row2 | Col2Row3|  
|---------------------------------------|  
| Col1 |  1        | 2        | 3       |  
|---------------------------------------|  
| Col2 |  4        | 5        | 6       |  
|---------------------------------------|
```

Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about conditional aggregation on union?

For example:

```
SELECT 
 MAX(RNC) AS RNC,
 MAX(CASE WHEN RowNr = 1 THEN Val END) AS [Row1],
 MAX(CASE WHEN RowNr = 2 THEN Val END) AS [Row2],
 MAX(CASE WHEN RowNr = 3 THEN Val END) AS [Row3]
FROM
(
     SELECT 0.1 AS ColNr, 'RCN1' AS RNC,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RowNamesCol1) AS RowNr, 
      RowNamesCol1 AS Val
     FROM YourTable
     WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 0.2 AS ColNr, 'RCN2' AS RNC,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RowNamesCol1) AS RowNr, 
      RowNamesCol2 AS Val
     FROM YourTable
     WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 1 AS ColNr, 'Col1' AS RNC,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RowNamesCol1) AS RowNr, 
      FORMAT(Col1, 'd') AS Val
     FROM YourTable
     WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 2 AS ColNr, 'Col2' AS RNC,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RowNamesCol2) AS RowNr, 
      FORMAT(Col2, 'd') AS Val
     FROM YourTable
     WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL
) q
GROUP BY ColNr
ORDER BY ColNr;
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/QIS75097)

**Returns:**

```
RNC     Row1        Row2        Row3
----    --------    ---------   ---------
RCN1    Col1Row1    Col1Row2    Col1Row3
RCN2    Col2Row1    Col2Row2    Col2Row3
Col1    1           2           3
Col2    4           5           6
```

Comment: Thanks A lot LukStorms, Anyways my requirement was like complete transpose of the table. As the column values of the two columns are important, So I had to make the first row from values of First Column and similarly the second row.

Comment: Hi, LukStorms, Can you please suggest if any other way to achieve the same output apart from pivot and unpivot,

Comment: Adapted for a different output.

Answer (score 0):

With pivoting it could be done like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM  
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rn,
        -- add row number w/o any strict sorting just to somehow 
        -- separate one row from another and to use in PIVOT part
        RowNamesCol1, -- all columns should be same datatype
        RowNamesCol2, -- I use varchar(50) as example 
        CAST(Col1 as varchar(50)) as Col1, 
        CAST(Col2 as varchar(50)) as Col2  
FROM Test) AS SourceTable  
UNPIVOT  
   ([value] FOR [key] IN (RowNamesCol1, RowNamesCol2, Col1, Col2)  
) AS unpvt
PIVOT  -- you need as much numbers as rows in your table
(MAX ([value]) FOR rn IN ([1], [2], [3])  
) AS pvt
```

Output:

```
|          key |        1 |        2 |        3 |
|--------------|----------|----------|----------|
|         Col1 |        1 |        2 |        3 |
|         Col2 |        4 |        5 |        6 |
| RowNamesCol1 | Col1Row1 | Col1Row2 | Col1Row3 |
| RowNamesCol2 | Col2Row1 | Col2Row2 | Col2Row3 |
```

Comment: Hi, gofr1, Thanks a lot for the help, Is there any other way to transpose the table like some matrix, apart form Pivot & Unpivot and here in pivot can we,control the order of rows (rownamescol1 and rownamescol2 to be 1st and 2nd rows instead of col1 and col2

Comment: Hi, in SQL Server you can make it through pivoting and another complex queries. For explicit sorting you can add something like `ORDER BY LEFT([key],1)+RIGHT([key],1) DESC`. And if you got many tables that you need to transpose you should adopt any of the solutions given here and make then dynamic SQL queries. You can use `sys.tables` and `sys.columns` tables, and count rows for `PIVOT` part, so you will dynamically create query with tables and columns you need and with `FOR [key] IN ([1],[2],...[n])`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to LukStorms and gofr1 for your valuable help. After some trials, I have come up with the following code:

```
SELECT piv.Cols AS RNC1, [Col1Row1], [Col1Row2], [Col1Row3] 
    FROM
        (
        SELECT RNC1, [Values], [Cols] 
            FROM 
                (SELECT Rownamescol1 AS RNC1, 
                        Rownamescol2 AS RNC2, 
                        CAST(Col1 AS VARCHAR(20)), 
                        CAST(Col1 AS VARCHAR(20)), 
                        CAST(Col1 AS VARCHAR(20)) 
                    FROM PivUnPiv3 
                 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 'rn','A','B','C', 'D'
                 )A
            UNPIVOT
                ([Values] FOR [Cols] IN ( RNC2, Col1, Col2))B 
        )C
    PIVOT
        (MAX([Values]) FOR RNC1 IN ([Col1Row1], [Col1Row2], [Col1Row3], [rn]))Piv
ORDER BY [rn]
```

The Result is:

```
| RNC1 | Col1Row1 | Col1Row2 | Col1Row3 |  
| RNC2 | Col2Row1 | Col2Row2 | Col2Row3 |  
| Col1 |        1 |        2 |        3 |  
| Col2 |        4 |        5 |        6 |  
| Col3 |        7 |        8 |        9 |
```

Comment: So that's how you wanted it !

Comment: Yeah, And I'm really unaware of the internals, that even though both queries (Yours latest updated and the above code) are achieving the same but which is better, in context of performance. assuming that it is run for specific result set as part another query